# Why is my OLED Arduino screen not working?

Tags: arduino-uno

Whenever I use My OLED display with my arduino, It doesn't work, and I have no Idea why. Here are my error messages,

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\cm_backtrace\cm_backtrace.c: In function 'cm_backtrace_init':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\cm_backtrace\cm_backtrace.c:144:13: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
fw_name = firmware_name;
^
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\cm_backtrace\cm_backtrace.c:145:12: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
hw_ver = hardware_ver;
^
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\cm_backtrace\cm_backtrace.c:146:12: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
sw_ver = software_ver;
^
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\tinyusb\rusb2\dcd_rusb2.c: In function 'wait_pipe_fifo_empty':
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\tinyusb\rusb2\dcd_rusb2.c:289:3: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
TU_ASSERT(num);
^~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\renesas_uno\1.0.5\cores\arduino\tinyusb\rusb2\dcd_rusb2.c:288:13: note: declared here
static void wait_pipe_fifo_empty(rusb2_reg_t* rusb, uint8_t num) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I tried looking online for any answers, but there seemed to be nothing.

In short, My OLED is still not working.

Comment: I am using an Arduino r4 WiFi

Comment: My OLED interface is SSD1306